# Nodemailer ya no envia correos, google desactivo la opcion de "Acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras"

Tags: nodejs, nodemailer

Alguien sabe alguna alternativa a nodemailer? o que se puede hacer ahora que google ya no permite el Acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras, lo cual inhabilita la opcion de enviar correos desde Nodejs con solo correo y contraseña

Comment: Usar un application password en la cuenta google asociada. La parte de "pedir alternativas" haría que una pregunta termine cerrada, además que cualquier aplicación va a tener el mismo problema si el lío es en la cuenta de correo...

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear una contraseña de aplicaciones  en tu cuenta de gmail , sigue estos pasos , luego la contraseña  la colocas en el código del nodemailer y listo .

- Administrar tu cuenta de Google
- Seguridad
- Verificación en dos pasos
- Contraseñas de aplicaciones